# repeating values and names error in strings.xml and other resources files

Tags: android

repeated names i want to use in color.xml, same names i want to use for different colors, but throwing an error.

> Error:Error: Found item
>   Color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material more than one time

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="abc_tint_btn_checkable">res/color/abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml</color>
    <color name="abc_tint_btn_checkable">res/color-v23/abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml</color>
    <color name="abc_tint_default">res/color/abc_tint_default.xml</color>
    <color name="abc_tint_default">res/color-v23/abc_tint_default.xml</color>
    <color name="abc_tint_edittext">res/color/abc_tint_edittext.xml</color>
    <color name="abc_tint_edittext">res/color-v23/abc_tint_edittext.xml</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use same name for different colors!

Just like your `identity card no.`!

Same `card no.` can't assign to different persons

Comment: but i want to use same color names in different layouts

Comment: You can use same color having same values in different layouts.